# Wireshark: count number of filter matches when one packet could match more than once

Tags: wireshark

I have a pcap of SCTP traffic and a filter clause that matches the payload in certain packets. I want to count how many such payloads exist. However, some packets contain multiple payloads (Nagle algorithm), so they could match the filter twice or more. Therefore, I only get a lower bound from filtering then checking the number of matching packets.

Is there  a way in Wireshark to count the total number of filter matches rather than the number of packets that match a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Given the filter expression provided below, namely `s1ap.procedureCode eq 9`, the CLI solution should probably be modified to something like this:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -Y "s1ap.procedureCode eq 9" -T fields -e s1ap.procedureCode | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep "^9" | wc -l
```

By *[`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)ing* for 9 specifically, you don't count lines where `s1ap.procedureCode` contains other values besides 9 in the same packet, but you still do count all occurrences of 9, even if more than one appears in the same packet.

And in this case, I don't think the I/O Graph method will work reliably, because you can only count fields, but you want to count fields only for specific values of the field.

**ORIGINAL** answer follows below where I had no information about the desired display filter expression.

---

If your SCTP filter represents an SCTP field, then the easiest way I can come up with to accomplish this is by using command-line tools, such as [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) and [`wc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc).  For example:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -Y "sctp.filter" -T fields -e frame.number -e sctp.filter | sed 's/,/\n/g' | wc -l
```

*NOTE: Replace sctp.filter with your SCTP display filter of choice.*

If you really want to use Wireshark, then you *can* accomplish this by using the I/O Graph, but IMO, it's as nice as the CLI solution.  For my test, here's what I did to produce the same result as the answer I got above:

From *"Statistics -> I/O Graph -> '+'*:

1. Enter an arbitrary name for your graph
2. Enter your display filter
3. Change Y-Axis to "`COUNT FIELDS (Y Field)`"
4. Enter your display filter again in the Y-Field
5. Be sure to enable your graph with a checkmark
6. Disable all other graphs
7. Set interval to 10 min (the max)
8. Select *Copy*
9. Paste the data into a spreadsheet program

If the duration of your packets is less than 10 minutes, you will have a heading and a single entry, which will be the number of occurrences of your filter, regardless of the number of packets.  If the duration of your packets is more than 10 minutes, then you will need to sum the occurrences to get a grand total.

Lastly, if your SCTP filter is not simply an SCTP field but a more complicated construct, then I'm not sure how to solve this, but posting your exact filter might help me (or someone else) come up with a solution.

Comment: I'll take a look in the morning and update ASAP. My filter is actually on some S1AP struct within the SCTP payload. It's something like `s1ap.procedureCode eq 9`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The updated answer worked for me. And yes, I much prefer command line tools :)